# How to make join of two different topics in kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic named **topic1** and a topic named **topic2**.
I have the following code:

-Stream of **topic1**:

```
KStream<Long, byte[]> events = builder.stream("topic1", Consumed.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.ByteArray()));
```

-Table of **topic2**:

```
KTable<Long, byte[]> table = builder.table("topic2",
        Consumed.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.ByteArray()));
```

When I produce with producer from **topic1**, everything is produced fine. The values for **topic1** and **topic2** are different, I want to consume the produced record from first topics producer with this stream "events" and after that append this events to the seconds topic table and save the state of the second topic value for the same key (Key is long, it's the same number for the first and second topic). In other words, I want to join stream with the table based on the same key and update table.

My code:

```
StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<Long, byte[]>> store = Stores
        .keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(STORE_TOPIC2), Serdes.Long(), Serdes.ByteArray())
        .withLoggingEnabled(new HashMap<>());

    builder.addStateStore(store);

    events.join(table, KeyValue::new, Joined.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.ByteArray(), Serdes.ByteArray()))
        .transform(Update::new, STORE_TOPIC2)
        .to("topic2", Produced.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.ByteArray()));
```

On the last line I produce the joined events to the topic2, but nothing is produced on this topic, my transformer "Update" looks like this:

```
private static class Update implements Transformer<Long, KeyValue<byte[], byte[]>, KeyValue<Long, byte[]>> {

    private KeyValueStore<Long, byte[]> store1;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        store1 = (KeyValueStore<Long, byte[]>) context.getStateStore(store);
    }

    @Override
    public KeyValue<Long, byte[]> transform(final Long key, final KeyValue<byte[], byte[]> updates) {

        System.out.println("Inside event transformer for key: " + key);
        System.out.println("Last produced graph: " + store.get(key));

        CustomClass c = null;
        try {
        c = deserializeModel(store.get(key));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (c == null) {
        c = new CustomClass(...);
        }

        try {
        return KeyValue.pair(companyKey, serializeModel(companyNetwork));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
        }
    }
```